# How to duplicate objects in variable with different variable names for PowerShell

Tags: object, powershell, duplicates

I would like to create a duplicate of same objects in different variable names.
The object I required is archive files from dotnetzip.

The following code is the full implementation:

```
   [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($zipFileDirectory + "Ionic.Zip.dll")
    $zipfile = [Ionic.Zip.ZipFile]::Read($zipfilename) 

    foreach ($file in $zipfile)
    {    
        $strSearchItem = [string]$file.FileName
        $strSearchItem = $strSearchItem.TrimEnd("/") 
        $newfile = $file.PSObject.Copy() 

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $newfile.Count; $i++)
    {

        if ($strSearchItem -like $searchFolderName + "/*")
        {
           $newFile[$i].FileName = $newFile[$i].FileName.Replace($searchFolderName + "/", "")
           $newFile[$i].Extract($fileDestination, [Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction]::OverWriteSilently) 

        }

    }
   } 

    $zipfile.Dispose()
```

For this purpose I need to be able to copy $file as separate entity from $zipfile, or at least retain the original default value for $file (making it read-only doesnt seemed viable). Is there any workaround for this matter? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

maybe

```
$newFile = $zipfile.PSObject.Copy()
```

in reply to @bdrc comment
example adding a comment to the zip

```
PS>$zf=[ionic.zip.zipfile]::read("c:\temp\zip\test.zip")
PS>$zf.comment
PS>$zf2=$zf.psobject.copy()
PS>$zf2.comment="TEST COMMENT"
PS>$zf2.save("c:\temp\test2.zip")
```

when opening original file with 7-zip I dont see the comment, I can see it in the new zipfile ...

Comment: It seems that this works like a pointer, the $zipfile is being modified when I change the value of $newFile.

Comment: I dont think so, i'm able  to add a comment to the clone object see my update

Comment: I was using $file in a foreach loop, and then replace the file name contained in the archive:
`code
foreach ($file in $zipfile)   <br/>
    { 
       $newfile = $file.PSObject.Copy()   <br/>
       $newFile.FileName = $newFile.FileName.Replace($searchFolderName, "")
    }
code`

Comment: do you still have a problem or not ?

Comment: Sorry the message got truncated. 
Yes, it shows that the $file and $newFile is the same, and foreach loop failed due to $file being modified.

Comment: you are not using copy() on the right object, you have got to copy $ zipfile and then look through it's files

Comment: I need to copy $file because $zipfile contains more than one archive objects, and I cant copy the $file before the foreach loop.

Comment: sorry but that'not clear to me .... i wa able to do smthg like `>$zf2 | %{$_.filename = "$($_.filename).newext"}`

Comment: I am still unable to achieve it. I've updated my question post.